# Electric displacement at the boundary of a dielectric and vaccum

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, dielectric

[image: Figure 1]At the boundary of an infinite linear dielectric with constant $\kappa$ and a vacuum, a charge q is placed. In order to calculate the electric displacement$(\mathbf{D})$ we can use Gauss's law for dielectrics i.e. $\oint\mathbf{D}\cdot d\mathbf{a}=Q_{fenc}$.

Now since the electric displacement vector does not depend on the dielectric, we can consider a sphere centered at q with radius $r$ and since $\mathbf D$ is spherical symmetric, the integral evaluates to: $$\mathbf D\cdot 4\pi r^2\hat r=q \Rightarrow \mathbf D= \frac{\hat r}{4\pi r^2}$$.

From this we can calculate the electric field for the two parts which is:$$\mathbf E= \frac{\hat r}{4\kappa\pi r^2};\Biggl\{^{\kappa=1\ vacuum}_{\kappa=\kappa\ dielectric}$$

But this is apparently incorrect and I don't understand why. Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: > *the electric displacement vector does not depend on the dielectric* -- This is not true. Integral over a closed surface does not depend on dielectric. D does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now since the electric displacement vector does not depend on the dielectric

Careful -- ${\bf D}$ *is* affected by the presence of a dielectric, just not in an immediately obvious way.  You need to use the properties of ${\bf E}$ and ${\bf D}$ fields at dielectric boundaries, specifically
\begin{align}
{\bf E}_{\parallel}=\text{ continuous}, {\bf E}_{\perp}=\text{ discontinuous}\\
{\bf D}_{\perp}=\text{ continuous}, {\bf D}_{\parallel}=\text{ discontinuous}
\end{align}
Perhaps this is enough to get you back on track?

Comment: Would the electric field depend on the dielectric? If it doesn’t, I can use gauss law and some symmetry on that?

Comment: Or do I consider gauss’s law on a hemisphere, and take the radial component to be the symmetric about the surface of the hemisphere

Comment: The problem with this is that it assumes ${\bf D}$ is radially symmetric, which I don't think is valid here.  I suspect you'll need to apply a method of images approach.  Have a look at this https://photonics101.com/dielectrics/the-precessing-dipole-molecule -- the very bottom addresses the case where the charge is placed on the boundary.

Comment: For the method of charges approach, you must have the charge density to be zero in the volume that we consider. But here we cannot be sure about that. Maybe if $\nabla \times \mathbf D =0$ , then there exist a potential function for the electric displacement. Using $ \nabla \cdot \mathbf D = \rho_{free}$ we can use the uniqueness theorem and then use the image of charges method?

Comment: I think what we're saying is we shall solve the problem where there is no charge density anywhere, just some point charges, and then apply the relevant boundary conditions (e.g. D_perp=constant along x=0 line).  By uniqueness this is the same problem as the above.

Comment: And yes I think in general electrostatic problems you can assume $\nabla\times{\bf D}=0$ as there will be no magnetic fields.